# MATLAB: apply a function to every n items in a vector

Tags: matlab

This related question [How can I apply a function to every row/column of a matrix in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307249/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-row-in-matlab) seems to indicate one way to do this is using num2cell, which I kind of want to stay away from.

Here's what I want to do. I've got an index list for a triangle mesh, the indices index the vertex list.

I want to run func(a,b,c) on the first 3 indices, then the next three indices, and so on.

So I could `reshape(idxs,3,[])` so now i've got my data into triplets as column vectors. But `arrayfun` does not do what I want it to do.

Looking for something like a column-map operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get your `func` properly vectorized, if necessary, such that the arguments can be lists of equal length:

```
vec_func = @(a,b,c)(arrayfun(@func,a,b,c))
```

Then, you can directly access every third element of `idxs`:

```
vec_func( idxs(1:3:end), idxs(2:3:end), idxs(3:3:end) )
```