# Deciphering a Function Handle Solution Found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13135833/560821

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

So... I can understand matlab function handles and its purposes. But sometimes, when it gets too cryptic, I require help in further elaborating it.
Take this example from the default MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html), say:

```
f = @(x)x.^3-2*x-5;
```

I can also re-write it as:

```
function f(arg)
  arg.^3 - 2*arg - 5;
end
```

Can anybody help out in deciphering the code below as previously mentioned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135833/560821)? I don't need help in the default matlab functions. Just a little help in understanding the user-defined anonymous functions here..

```
applyToGivenRow = @(func, matrix) @(row) func(matrix(row, :))
applyToRows = @(func, matrix) arrayfun(applyToGivenRow(func, matrix), 1:size(matrix,1))'
% Example
myMx = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
myFunc = @sum;
applyToRows(myFunc, myMx)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
applyToGivenRow = @(func, matrix) @(row) func(matrix(row, :))
```

This is a function that creates another function, eg the following (as taken from the Question's example)

```
applyToGivenRow(@myFunc,myMx)
```

would evaluate to the function

```
@(row) myFunc(myMx(row,:))
```

Then

```
applyToRows = @(func, matrix) arrayfun(applyToGivenRow(func, matrix), 1:size(matrix,1))'
```

uses this `applyToGivenRow` function. Arrayfun loops through the vector you feed it (`1:size(matrix,1)`) and evaluates the function you feed (`applyToGivenRow(func, matrix)`) it for each value in the vector.

The original author could have also shortened it down to

```
applyToRows = @(func, matrix) arrayfun(@(row) func(matrix(row, :), 1:size(matrix,1))'
```

Read the documentation about [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), and it should be easy to understand this.