# How to avoid a for-loop in MATLAB, when performing a operation on each row in a very large matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix, bsxfun

I am using **MATLAB**. I have *very large* **sparse matrices**, and I want to perform a `logical` or `bsxfun` on each column of this matrix. There is a single `for` loop where in it is a single operation of `logical` to fill a sparse matrix. Here I include a sample function with some fake small data to see what I am trying to do;

```
function maskMat()
graph_temp = round(rand(10,10));
tic;
com_mat = round(rand(10,10));
com = round(rand(10,1));
for ii=1:length(graph_temp)    
    com_mat(:,ii) = logical(com ~= com(ii));
    %bsxfun works too but is slightly slower
    %com_mat(:,ii) =  bsxfun(@ne,com,com(ii));
end
toc;
com_mat = graph_temp .* com_mat;
```

`graph_temp` and `com_mat` are much bigger with around **1M** rows and columns and the code is horribly slow do to the `for` loop. There is another relevant question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2307249/410975), but I have not understood the theory behind it to see if I can apply those solutions to this problem as well.

I was thinking to either write a `mex` c++ function or try to get some sort of nested `arrayfun` so that each `logical`/`bsxfun` operation is called as a subroutine of a greater function to avoid the for loop bottle neck.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to combine `com` with `com_mat`? Otherwise I don't understand why you initialize `com_mat` with `rand` instead of just `zeros`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, `com_mat` before being *masked* at the end by `graph_temp`, is simply the matrix of logicals for set of all `(i,j)` pairs that equal each other. Where in the `com` vector it is the expansion of the pairwise comparisons. So if we had half of `com` being `0` and the other half `1`, I want `com_mat`, before the last step, to be the matrix of which association are not equal. Make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I followed your code all the way. 
So, to make sure, is `com_mat(ii,jj)` equals to `com(ii) ~= com(jj)`?

If so try the following options

```
com_mat = bsxfun( @ne, com, com' ); %' creates entire matrix at once
com_mat = graph_temp .* com_mat;  % do the masking
```

Since you are dealing with sparse matrices, why don't you take advantage of it

```
[ii jj] = find( graph_temp );
[m n] = size( graph_temp );
com_mat = sparse( ii, jj, com(ii) ~= com(jj), m, n );
```

Comment: I used the `sparse` matrix code, and it's super fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try this way, but I don't have access to Matlab at the moment

`arrayfun(@(i) ~isequal(A(:,i),B),1:10,'UniformOutput',false)`

Comment: If you're after speed performance, `arrayfun` isn't necessarily faster than an ordinary for loop: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why).

Comment: I know but perhaps the OP has a pre JIT Matlab release.