# Finding similar rows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

I have a matrix with a large number of rows.  I have another matrix that I will loop through one row at a time.  For each row in the second matrix, I need to look for similar rows in the first matrix.  Once all the similar rows are found, I need to know the row numbers of the similar rows.  These rows will almost never be exact, so `ismember` does not work.

Also, the solution would preferably (not necessarily, however) give some way to set a level of similarity that would trigger the code to say it is similar and give me the row number.

Is there any way to do this?  I've looked around, and I can't find anything.

Comment: What is your measure of similarity, eucliadean distance? `pdist2` should help you

Comment: @ServerS Note also that `pdist2` can be used with other distances, not just Euclidean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use cosine distance, which finds the angle between two vectors. Similar vectors (in your case, a row and your comparison vector) have a value close to 1 and dissimilar vectors have a value close to 0.

```
function d = cosSimilarity(u, v)
  d = dot(u,v)/(norm(u)*norm(v));
end
```

To apply this function to each to all pairs of rows in the matrices `M` and `V` you could use nested `for` loops. Hardly the most elegant, but it will work:

```
numRowsM = size(M, 1)
numRowsV = size(V, 1)
similarThresh = .9

for m = 1:numRowsM
    for v = 1:numRowsV 
        similarity = cosSimilarity(V(v,:), M(m, :))

        % Notify about similar rows
        if similarity > similarThresh
            disp([num2str(m) ' is similar to a row in V'])
        end
    end
end
```

Instead of nested `for` loops, there are definitely other ways. You could start by looking at the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307249/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-row-in-matlab) question, which will help you avoid the loop by converting the rows of the matrix into cells of a cell array and then applying the function with `cellfun`.

Comment: So `V` is my second matrix?

Comment: Agh, thought V was a vector you wanted to compare. Misread your question. So you want to compare each row in V against each row in M? Will revisit soon

Comment: Right, although there will always be less values in V than in M.  I want the row numbers of the similar rows in M.

Comment: Ok nested `for` loops should work, but there are likely nicer solutions.