# Vectorized processing of each N-dimension array in (N+1)-dimension array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm looking for a vectorized method of processing *k* identically-sized N-dimensional arrays provided as an *N+1*-dimension array in Matlab.

If a general solution is not available, then a specific solution where *N* = 2, perhaps?

The closest thing I've found is `pagefun` which applies a function to each 2-dimensional page in a 3-dimensional parameter, but (in a reversal of the common situation) it seems that can only be used with GPU data.

Basically, a vectorized version of

```
function R = apply(fn, M)
for i = size(M)(1, end)
    R(:,:,..,i) = fn(M(:,:,..,i));
end
```

Comment: Is `bsxfun` what you are looking for?

Comment: The answer depends on the specific function you want to apply. It may be possible to vectorize it or not

Comment: I think your question is basically a duplicate of this one: [How can I apply a function to every row/column of a matrix in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2307249/52738) You're simply extending it to higher dimensions than just the rows (dimension 1) or columns (dimension 2), but the premise is still the same.